# How do I deploy to cloud -> i have a flask app running on nginx dockerized in two different containers

Tags: docker, nginx, flask, cloud

So my file structure is:

```
Main_Folder:

----flask_app (folder / container)
----nginx (folder / container)
----docker-compose.yml
```

I want to deploy it to a GCP micro instance (compute engine)

The only tutorials i could find online were to deploy a single container

How do i deploy 2 containers and get it running like my local host with "docker-compose up" using the docker-compose.yml file ?

Comment: Install docker compose and run it! Don't see what's the problem here... In addition, why do you need nginx container? For SSL management?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere yeah! I read somewhere that you can't run two docker containers on one compute engine instance, also it had a heavy machine learning model which made it all the more difficult, 
Anyhow i have now deployed it on cloud run which was a breeze

Comment: You were able to deploy your heavy ML model on Cloud Run? Managed platform or on GKE?

Comment: On the cloud run managed platform, it wasnt really a very heavy model, the trained model was around 90mb , and the entire docker image was 3GB. also to mention, there is no on the go training involved on the cloud.

Comment: Great!! Cloud Run managed is awesome!! And more and more amazing features are coming. Stay tuned!